# Java Garbage Collection Behavior

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

Does the Garbage Collector on Android devices only collect objects that are orphaned AND it considers too large, or does it collect all orphaned objects regardless of size?

I am doing a test where I rapidly push and pop an Activity on and off the stack several times and then take a look at the heap.

If the Activity in question contains no code, then I end up with several instances of it showing up in a heap dump, even after forcing a GC.

However, if I add a large variable to this activity like a large byte array, then the GC seems to behave as desired/expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Garbage collectors pay no attention to the size of the objects that they are collecting.  They are indiscriminate.  If the GC detects that an object is unreachable, it collects it.

What you are probably observing is a different effect.  A typical garbage collector only runs when the JVM determines that there is enough garbage to be worth collecting.  The problem is that the workload of a collection has two parts:

1. finding unreachable objects
2. collecting the unreachable objects

In a typical modern collector, finding the unreachable objects involves traversing and marking all reachable objects: the unreachable objects are the ones that were not marked.  Then collecting the unreachable objects is typically done by moving all of the reachable objects.

This means that the work done by the GC is proportional to the amount of non-garbage.  Therefore, a GC will work most efficiently if the ratio of garbage to non-garbage is high.  The simplest measure of that is when the heap is full or close to full.

So what you are probably seeing is that allocation of larger objects is causing the heap to fill sooner, and triggering the GC to run.  When the objects are small, the heap doesn't fill, and the GC doesn't run (yet).

As for "forcing" the GC, the behavior of a `System.gc()` call is highly platform specific.  On some platforms it will trigger a full GC, on others it will do absolutely nothing ... and various points in between.

Answer (score 1):

Eventually it collects everything regardless of size.  What it collects when after it becomes elligible for collection is implementation specific and should not be relied upon.